# Scope of `this` within object declaration

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, scope

When creating an object in JavaScript, `this` doesn't seem to point to the object I'm creating.

In the example below, the `anArrayValue` should be `"a"`, but it's being logged as `undefined`.

```js
const anArray = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

const anObject = {
  arrayIndex: 0,

  // I want to use anObject.arrayIndex here, but it's undefined
  anArrayValue: anArray[this.arrayIndex],

  log() {
    console.log(this.anArrayValue);
  }
};

//logs undefined
anObject.log();     

//logs 'a'
console.log(anArray[anObject.arrayIndex]);
```

Comment: this always points to the call of execution context. that's a literal object who's declaration is being executed at window context. and therefore this.arrayIndex is calling for window.arrayIndex. You'll need a real object for that kind of reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'this.arrayIndex' is actually interpreted as 'window.arrayIndex' (this refers to global "window" object here in the browser).

You may want to try the code below in your JavaScript console not to dump the whole global object in the StackOverflow snippet.

```js
const anArray = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
const anObject = {
      arrayIndex: 0,
      anArrayValue: anArray[(function(arg){console.log('this :', this); return arg.arrayIndex})(this)],
      log() {
        console.log(this.anArrayValue);
      }
    };
```

And this global object obviously does not have any `arrayIndex` property unless explicitly created :

```js
const anArray = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
arrayIndex = 0; // here we create the arrayIndex for the global object
const anObject = {
      arrayIndex: 0,
      anArrayValue: anArray[this.arrayIndex],
      log() {
        console.log(this.anArrayValue);
      }
    };

console.log("anObject.anArrayValue :", anObject.anArrayValue);
```

`log()` on the other hand is an object method, and as such, `this` refers to the object it belongs to :

> When a function is called as a method of an object, its this is set to the object the method is called on.

Reference : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

No, during object construction *this* does *not* refer to the object youre in. If it would be like this objects would not be stable and could not be optimized. However you could simply move the `arrayIndex` outside of it:

```
const anArray = ['a', 'b', 'c'], arrayIndex = 0;

const anObject = {
  arrayIndex,     
  anArrayValue: anArray[arrayIndex],

  log() {
    console.log(this.anArrayValue);
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

`this` context can't be used upon declaration. However, you can use a [getter](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) to return the value, which will be executed upon call (and therefor have access to `this`).

```js
    const anArray = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

    const anObject = {
      arrayIndex: 0,
      // Use a getter to execute the expression upon call
      get anArrayValue() { return anArray[this.arrayIndex] },
      log() {
        console.log(this.anArrayValue);
      }
    };
    anObject.log();
    //logs 'a'
    console.log(anArray[anObject.arrayIndex]);
    //logs 'a'
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that `this.arrayIndex` isn't doing what you think it is.

Consider this example:

```js
let parent = {
    a: ['parent a'],
    method() {
        let child = { a: ['child a'], b: this.a[0] };
        console.log(child.b);
    }
}

parent.method(); // Outputs 'parent a', not 'child a'
//^^^^           // <-- This decides that `this` is.
```

When declaring an object like that, the only time `this` will reference the object you are creating is when it's inside a function assigned to that object.

To be clear, `this` always references the object that contains the function you're calling. This means that if you assigned `method` to a different object and then called it, it would reference the new object.

Example:

```
let newObject = { a: ['newObject a'], method: parent.method };
newObject.method(); // This outputs 'newObject a'
```

The exception to this is when you use fat arrow (`() =>`) function declarations, in which case `this` is inherited from the scope that declared the function, no matter where the function is called from.

Answer (score 0):

"this" is defined at the beginning of the function call. Here, you are not in anObjet's method. You must store the value prior to declaring the object.

```
const anArray = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

const DEFAULT_ARRAY_INDEX = 0;

const anObject = {
    arrayIndex: DEFAULT_ARRAY_INDEX,

    anArrayValue: anArray[DEFAULT_ARRAY_INDEX],

    log: function() {
        console.log(anObject.anArrayValue);
    }
};

anObject.log();     

console.log(anArray[anObject.arrayIndex]);
```

You can also have an "initialize" method. Or make a class with a constructor.